# Datepicker with default value is today

Tags: php, datepicker

I have a page "nnnx.php" which has a datepicker. The date input will be: `$nnnx = $_POST['nnnx'];`

I want when open nnnx.php, default value of input is today: `$nnnx = $today;` (= `date("Y/m/d")`)
and when datepicker the value `input, $nnnx = $_POST['nnnx'];`

(It is similar to this page: https://www.history.com/this-day-in-history)

Can you help me, please? Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to check if `$_POST['nnnx']` is there, then set the value. You can do this easily with a ternary:

```
$today = !empty($_POST['nnnx']) ? $_POST['nnnx'] : date('Y-m-d');
```

Comment: How simple it is! but effective. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [null coalescing operator](https://www.php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op)

```php
$nnnx = $_POST['nnnx'] ?? date('Y-m-d');
```